# Bouncing buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I didnt found any solution on the internet so I decided to ask my question here. There is this cool animation effect you can make with a buttton that if you tap it it jumps and lands like a pop. If you know what I mean. I simply mean that the button bounces like a rubberbal if you hit the floor once. I saw this effect on many different gaming apps and would like to do this in my app. It is actually like making the button bigger and immediatly smaller if it was tapped. Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this blog](http://danielsaidi.wordpress.com/2012/09/03/ios-bounce-animation/) which describes about bounce effect on icon. That should guide you to right direction. Also [check this lantean blog](http://www.lantean.com.ar/coreanimation-bounce-animation-like-camera-button/) and [this cocoanetics blog.](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/06/lets-bounce/)

This is the code he is using,

```
+ (CAKeyframeAnimation*)dockBounceAnimationWithViewHeight:(CGFloat)viewHeight
{
    NSUInteger const kNumFactors    = 22;
    CGFloat const kFactorsPerSec    = 30.0f;
    CGFloat const kFactorsMaxValue  = 128.0f;
    CGFloat factors[kNumFactors]    = {0,  60, 83, 100, 114, 124, 128, 128, 124, 114, 100, 83, 60, 32, 0, 0, 18, 28, 32, 28, 18, 0};

    NSMutableArray* transforms = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < kNumFactors; i++)
    {
        CGFloat positionOffset  = factors[i] / kFactorsMaxValue * viewHeight;
        CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0.0f, -positionOffset, 0.0f);

        [transforms addObject:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform]];
    }

    CAKeyframeAnimation* animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    animation.repeatCount           = 1;
    animation.duration              = kNumFactors * 1.0f/kFactorsPerSec;
    animation.fillMode              = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.values                = transforms;
    animation.removedOnCompletion   = YES; // final stage is equal to starting stage
    animation.autoreverses          = NO;

    return animation;
}

- (void)bounce:(float)bounceFactor
{
    CGFloat midHeight = self.frame.size.height * bounceFactor;
    CAKeyframeAnimation* animation = [[self class] dockBounceAnimationWithViewHeight:midHeight];
    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"bouncing"];
}
```

Comment: one moment I need to test this if it works

Comment: where is the button in this code? actually: how can I connect this to a button IBOutlet?

Comment: @NoahRaissi, I would recommend you to go through that blog and understand the code. Then you can tweak this based on your requirement. This may not be a ready made solution to your problem.

Comment: @NoahRaissi, Instead of self, you need to specify your button.

Comment: okay I'm gonna test that now.

Comment: well I understood the code but this wasnt something that I was looking for. The code is that the button bounces to...the north of the screen... I and I want to that the button bounces to the view of the user If you know what I mean.

Comment: @NoahRaissi, Okay, then i misunderstood your question. But anyways check with this code and see if you can achieve whatever you were planning. Also check the other two links.

Comment: AHH wait I found an example to show you what I mean. Do you have bad piggies or angry birds space...

Comment: On the start menu you can see the play button and if you tap it you can see the bouncing that I mean.

Comment: Okay. let me check. I will update if I can get a solution.

Comment: @NoahRaissi, Did you actually check this link which was mentioned in my answer? http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/06/lets-bounce/. From the video, it seems like the bounce effect is what mentioned there. Play the video and check.

Comment: yes but it still bounce not like angrybirds or some other apps do.

Comment: @NoahRaissi, Yes, you might have to make some adjustments to that code. I am not sure if you will get a perfect code like that.

Comment: I'm gonna do that tomorrow because I'm to tired now. Thumbs up for your help. :D